# How to collect TCP stats on Windows? For further NIC optimisation

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, tcp

**I want to collect statistics on how big TCP packets are on incoming traffic.**

The box is Windows 2008 R2.

I want to optimise NIC settings for the particulare shape of the traffic I have.

*Anything else would you suggest to capture?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Microsoft Network Monitor and analyze the packets that way.

[Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865)

Comment: but thats just a sniffer... i am getting high number of packets. how can i effectively collect stats and calculate distribution of packet size? or you are talking to get 10 samples and calculate with Casio in hand...

Comment: I could collect packet sizes. need to export them into excel somehow.